# is adsense allowed on social networking websites

Tags: adsense

i got an email from google this morning that my account would not be approved due to insufficient content . i run a social networking site which does not have contents but more of users images e.t.c is adsense allowed on social networks or dating sites .. see email below

Your AdSense application status

As mentioned in our welcome email, we conduct a second review of your AdSense application once AdSense code is placed on your site(s). As a result of this review, we have disapproved your account for the following violation(s):

We did not approve your application for the reasons listed below

Insufficient content: To be approved for AdSense and show relevant ads on your site, your pages need to have enough text on them for our specialists to review and for our crawler to be able to determine what your pages are about.

To resolve this issue, please work through the following suggestions:

Make sure that your pages have sufficient text - websites that contain mostly images, videos or Flash animations will not be approved.
Your content should contain complete sentences and paragraphs, not only headlines.
Ensure that your website is fully built and launched before you apply for AdSense - do not apply while your site’s still in a beta or “under construction” phase or only consists of a website template.
Place the ad code on a live page of your website. It does not have to be the main page, but test pages that are empty except for the AdSense ad code will not be approved.
Provide a clear navigation system for your visitors so that they can easily find all of the sections and pages of your website.
If you’d like to monetize YouTube videos, please apply for the YouTube monetization program. Note that blogs and websites that contain only videos will not be approved.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a coding question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines. If you have questions about Google's policies, address them to Google via their support pages. We are not Google policy support. (And the email you received tells you precisely why your application was rejected - insufficient textual content that can be parsed to determine which ads to display - and what you need to do to fix it. Read the text you copied and pasted here, and do what it tells you to do.)

Comment: (continued) It also says (very clearly) that **websites that contain mostly images...will not be approved**. As you've said your site **consists mostly of images**, I'd think you could pretty clearly figure out why your application was rejected.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should have been closed five years ago for the reasons given above.

Answer (score -1):

No, you can't.

See tutorial : https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/48182?hl=en